# Why does the code in the description not work, it is meant to change the rgb value gradually

Tags: lua, roblox

This is in Roblox Lua by the way. If you are wondering what the result is, it is just a black block that doesn't change color.

```
local part = Instance.new("Part")
part.Parent = game.Workspace
local maxRGBValue = 99*3
local r = 0
local g = 0
local b = 0
while r + g + b ~= maxRGBValue do
    wait(1)
    local r = r + 10
    local g = g + 10
    local b = b + 10
    part.Color = Color3.fromRGB(r,g,b)
end
local r = 0
local g = 0
local b = 0
```

Comment: Please don't edit a question to replace it in a way that makes an existing answer not apply. You can ask another question instead (and maybe link to the earlier one if that would help).

Answer (score 1):

The `local` syntax creates a brand new variable every time the program reaches that statement. So you actually have three different variables named `r`, three named `g`, and three named `b`, essentially as though the code were:

```
local part = Instance.new("Part")
part.Parent = game.Workspace
local maxRGBValue = 99*3
local r1 = 0
local g1 = 0
local b1 = 0
while r1 + g1 + b1 ~= maxRGBValue do
    wait(1)
    local r2 = r1 + 10
    local g2 = g1 + 10
    local b2 = b1 + 10
    part.Color = Color3.fromRGB(r2,g2,b2)
end
local r3 = 0
local g3 = 0
local b3 = 0
```

So the values of `r1`, `g1`, and `b1` never change from the initial zero values, `r2`, `g2`, and `b2` are always exactly 10 every time, and variables `r3`, `g3`, and `b3` are useless.

You should generally put `local` only at the first mention of each variable. Also, if you want the variable's value to stay what it was over different iterations of a loop or between different calls to a function, make sure that `local` declaration is before that loop or function.

So probably better (but not tested):

```
local part = Instance.new("Part")
part.Parent = game.Workspace
local maxRGBValue = 99*3
local r = 0
local g = 0
local b = 0
while r + g + b < maxRGBValue do
    wait(1)
    r = r + 10
    g = g + 10
    b = b + 10
    part.Color = Color3.fromRGB(r,g,b)
end
```

I also changed `~= maxRGBValue` to `< maxRGBValue`. The loop wouldn't ever terminate using the check for equality, since `r+g+b` will step from `90*3` to `100*3` and is never equal to `99*3`.

Comment: can you tell me why the new code does not work @aschepler